# Javascript : Extracting the digits from different positions from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below

```
Original string  : results

1apple23oranges  : 1 , 23

4apples1oranges  : 4, 1

25oranges        : 25
```

By regular expression or any, i can't figure out how to get the above results as pure digits in javascript.

Any idea pls?

Answer (score 7):

Use the regular expression `\d+`, which means any digit from 0 to 9 (`\d`) repeated one or more times (`+`). The qualifier `g` will make the search global (ie: don't stop on the first hit).

```
resultArray = original.match(/\d+/g);
```

This will result an array with all the numbers, to join them using ", " a separator, use the function `join()`

```
resultString = original.match(/\d+/g).join(", ");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
'1apple23oranges'.match(/\d+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use match function on your string object with expression .match(/\d+/g).

Eg. var a = "1apple23oranges"

```
 var res = a.match(/\d+/g)
```

You can separate each values by comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"1apple23oranges".match(/(\d+)/g);`

Note: If you need the digits as integer value then you have to use `parseInt` for that. If you are using jQuery then you can have all the integers in an array

```
var arr = new Array(); 
$.each("1apple23oranges".match(/(\d+)/g), function(index, value){ arr.push(parseInt(value, 10));});
```